# How can I calculate the pH of the solution created by reacting sodium with water?

Tags: ph

> $\pu{23mg}$ of sodium was added to $\pu{100cm3}$ of water.
>
> - What is the pH of the solution produced?

$$\ce{2Na + 2H2O -> H2 + 2NaOH}$$

So firstly to find the moles, I've divided $\pu{0.023g}$ by $23$ to reach $\pu{0.001 mol}$.

Am I correct that the concentration of $\ce{NaOH}$ would be $\pu{0.01mol\,dm^{-3}}$?
$[\ce{OH-}] = 0.01$ which should be multiplied by $2$ due to the balancing numbers.
So $K_\mathrm{w}$ divided by $0.02$ gives $5\times10^{-3}$
$$
\mathrm{pH} = -\log[\ce{H+}]\\
\mathrm{pH} = 12
$$

- Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. Please note that the proper term for "number of moles" is [amount of substance](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00297.html). The former would be the same as referring to the mass as "number of kilograms".

Answer (score 3):

You answer is right, but your reasoning is not.

Amount of $\ce{Na} = \frac{0.023}{23} = 0.001$ mole

$[\ce{NaOH}]= \frac{0.001}{0.100} (\mathrm{moleL^-1}) = 0.01$ M

$\downarrow$

$p\ce{OH} = 2 \to p\ce{H} = 14 - 2 = 12$